# IE7 Menu HasLayout issue

Tags: css

So I have been Googling and I am quite sure my problem emerge from the hasLayout issues with IE7 and lower.

My problem:
[See image here](http://mhlhost.com/stack.jpg)

The HTML Code under here. The problem lies between the id="header" div and the id="colortab" div.

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="logo"><img src="images/logo.gif" border="0" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="hotline"><img src="images/ds_garanti.png" border="0" alt="" /></div>
</div>
<div id="colortab" class="ddcolortabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php" title="Forside"><span>Forside</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Vi tilbyder" rel="dropmenu1_a"><span>Vi tilbyder</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Tilbud" rel="dropmenu2_a"><span>Faste Tilbud</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="ds-garanti.php" title="Garanti"><span>Garanti</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="kontakt.php" title="Kontakt"><span>Kontakt</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<!--1st drop down menu -->                                                   
<div id="dropmenu1_a" class="dropmenudiv_a">
<a href="staal-smedearbejde.php">Stål og smedearbejde</a>
<a href="vvs-arbejde.php">VVS arbejde</a>
<a href="udlejning.php">Udlejning</a>
</div>

<!--2nd drop down menu -->                                                   
<div id="dropmenu2_a" class="dropmenudiv_a">
<a href="tilbud-staal-smedearbejde.php">Tilbud på stål og smedearbejde</a>
<a href="tilbud-vvs-arbejde.php">Tilbud på VVS arbejde</a>
<a href="tilbud-udlejning.php">Tilbud på udlejning</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//SYNTAX: tabdropdown.init("menu_id", [integer OR "auto"])
tabdropdown.init("colortab", 3)
</script>
```

And the belonging CSS can be seen here http://mhlhost.com/stackstyle.css

Very much appriciated if someone can help me out here. I can't figure out which elements causes me trouble :(

Comment: Its very hard to answer that question from just looking at the source and CSS. If I can see the live site, I'd probably be able to help more. Static analysis on CSS, especially considering IE, is not really something a human can do.

Comment: okay I mainly just don't want google to pick up the url.
so here it is mhlhost dot com / nygsmede

Comment: If you use IE8 you can enable compability mode and it will show you the extra space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating the header left will close the gap in ie6/7.

```
#header{
    position:relative; 
    height:100px; 
    background-color:#fff; 
    width:855px;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: I cannot thank you enough, I really mean that! solved hours of frustration.. that litle line.. care to explain why?

Comment: I don't remember which of the many ie6 vertical space bugs this fixes. I've been using it for years whenever I have to do a rounded-corner box.  It's not hasLayout since your header hasLayout from having width.